# Exporting and importing in Node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating my first project in Node and someone told me that it is a good practise to create a `.js` file having all the common and frequently used function

For example suppose I want to query something to my mongoose, to fetch data or update data, I should create a `js` file from where all the operations should happen.

Consider I have a Mongoose Schema which looks like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: String,
    email: String,
    passowrd: String, 
    image: String
}) 


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

To perform a function such as checking if the user exsist in the Db, I created a .js file in my helper `function folder` known as `my_db_query.js` where I imported my mongoose schema and made  many common function which interact with my schema (or other schemas in my mongoose)

```
    Const user = requeire(./../model/user.js) 
    //other schema

       function findByEmail (email) {
       return User.findOne({email: email}).then((currentUser) => {
           return currentUser
    } 

    function updateUser (updatedData) {
     //to update user
    }

    function deleteUser (user) {
   //to delete a user
}
```

Now, Suppose I have a folder routes where I need to use them.

```
route.delete("/:delete", isAdmin, (req, res) => {
})

route.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
})

route.put(/:id, isAdmin, (req, res) => {
})
```

**Question:** How can I able to export all function at once and how can I import and use them in my routes file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.js` file, you can export whatever functions you would like to use in other parts of your code base. The below is an example of what should go at the bottom of your `.js` file. It will export the 3 functions you defined.

```
module.exports = {
    findByEmail, 
    updateUser, 
    deleteUser
}
```

In your routes file you can then import the file/functions. At the top of your routes file you need to include the below. In the below example, `commonMethods.js` is the file name of the `.js` file and all of the files are located in the same directory.

```
const commonMethods = require('./commonMethods.js')
```

You can then use any of the common methods like this: `commonMethods.updateUser(updatedData)`

Answer (score 3):

> How can I able to export all function at once ?

```
 module.exports = { findByEmail, updateUser, deleteUser };
```

Just export an object containing the functions.

> and how can I import and use them in my routes file ?

You could destructure the exported object:

```
 const { findByEmail, updateUser, deleteUser } = require("./my_db_query");

 findByEmail("test@example.com").then(/*...*/).catch(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Export all function at once:

I prefer to encapsulate everything inside an object.

```
const index = {};
index.findByEmail = function() { ... }
index. updateUser = function() { ... }
index. deleteUser = function() { ... }

module.export = index;
```

> Import 1

```
const lib = require('./lib.js');
```

> Import 2
>       const {findByEmail, updateUser , deleteUser } = required('./lib.js');